# ASP.NET VB Nested Listviews

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an outer listview and inside its itemtemplate an inner listview. Each has its own SQLDataSource. A Id field from the outerlistview works as a select parameter for the second listview.

When stepping through with the debugger it works perfectly, unfortunately the rendered page only contains data from the outer listview. It appears the databinding of the outer listview fires and renders the page (including the inner listview) before the codebehind can provide a where parameter to the second listview.

The aspx page is below.

```
<%@ Page Title="Nested ListView" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/SimpleMasterPage.master"
    CodeFile="NLV2PA_A.aspx.vb" Inherits="Demos_NLV2PA_A" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder1" DataKeyNames="Id"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <span>ListView 1 No data was returned. </span>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <span style="">Id:
                <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                Name:
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
            </span>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder2"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <span>ListView2 No data was returned. </span>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">Title:
                        <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <h1>
                            <%# Eval("Title") %></h1>
                        <br />
                        Summary:
                        <asp:Label ID="SummaryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Summary") %>' />
                        <br />
                        PhotoAlbumID:
                        <asp:Label ID="PhotoAlbumIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PhotoAlbumId") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RenaissanceConnectionString1 %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [PhotoAlbum] ORDER BY [Id]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RenaissanceConnectionString1 %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Title], [Summary], [PhotoAlbumId] FROM [Apartments] WHERE ([PhotoAlbumId] = @PAId)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" DefaultValue="0" Name="PAId" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

The code behind is

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters("PAId").DefaultValue = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("IdLabel"), Label).Text
    End If
End Sub
```

The output to the browser is:

```
Id: 8 
Name: First set of Photos 

ListView2 No data was returned.

Id: 9 
Name: Second set of Photos 

ListView2 No data was returned.

etc.
```

---

Microsoft make the point in an old article that:

> You could, in theory, intercept the
>   ItemDataBound event of the parent
>   ListView, walk your way through the
>   control tree, grab a reference to the
>   child ListView, and bind it
>   programmatically to data. If you do,
>   you won't throw an exception, but the
>   binding command on the inner ListView
>   is lost because it fires too late to
>   affect the rendering.

Unfortunately, they don't tell me how to fix it.

If there is any genius out there who could tell me how to get this to work it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Put your **SqlDataSource2** *inside* the **ItemTemplate** of **ListView1**.
2. for your **ControlParameter**, set **ControlID="IdLabel"** and **PropertyName="Text"**

You wont need any code behind

Comment: Brilliant it worked. Well done DavRob60. I will put your name forward for a New Year's honour - Knighthood OK?